# Java collect to list but specify pre-defined first two elements order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have a `List<Person>` objects. From it I want to get a list of all id's, and I always want the id "abc" and "bob" to come as the 0th and 1st index of the list if available. Is there a way to do this with java streams?

```
class Person {
   private String id;
}

List<Person> allPeople = ...
List<String> allIds = allPeople.stream().map(Person::id).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My approach is:

```
Set<String> allIds = allPeople.stream().map(Person::id).collect(Collectors.Set());
List<String> orderedIds = new ArrayList<>();
if(allIds.contains("abc")) {
   orderedIds.add("abc");
}
if(allIds.contains("bob")) {
   orderedIds.add("bob");
}
//Iterate through the set and all add all entries which are not bob and abc in the list.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you need more of a `PriorityQueue` rather than a `List` here, so may be something like this:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq = list.stream()
            .map(Person::getId)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new PriorityQueue<>(
                    Comparator.comparing(x -> !"abc".equals(x))
                            .thenComparing(x -> !"bob".equals(x)))));
```

If you still need a `List` though, just drain that `pq` into one:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
   result.add(pq.poll());
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I think you could use this comparator in List.sort() or in Stream.sorted(). Well actually a similar comparator that compares Person objects using this same technique.

Comment: @StuartMarks right, don't know why I started with a `PriorityQueue`. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I assume that each id occurs only once in the list. With this I would choose a simple straightforward solution:

```
List<Person> allPeople = ...;
List<String> allIds = allPeople.stream().map(Person::id).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
boolean foundBob = allIds.remove("bob");
if (foundBob) allIds.add(0, "bob");
boolean foundAbc = allIds.remove("abc");
if (foundAbc) allIds.add(0, "abc");
```

Note that `"bob"` and `"abc"` are moved to the head of the list in reverse order. So `"abc"` is first in the end.

You can make a small utility method for moving an element:

```
static void moveToHead(List<String> list, String elem) {
  boolean found = list.remove(elem);
  if (found) list.add(0, elem);
}
```

With this your code is even simpler and easier to understand:

```
List<Person> allPeople = ...;
List<String> allIds = allPeople.stream().map(Person::id).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
moveToHead(allIds, "bob");
moveToHead(allIds, "abc");
```

Comment: You should use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)` then, as `toList()` does not guaranty to return a mutable `List`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to perform this in a "fully" stream pipeline you could do:

```
allPeople.stream()
         .map(Person::id)
         .distinct()
         .collect(collectingAndThen(partitioningBy(s -> "abc".equals(s) || "bob".equals(s)), 
                    map -> Stream.concat(map.get(true).stream(), map.get(false).stream())));
         .collect(toList());
```

if you always want "abc" in front of "bob" then change

```
map.get(true).stream()
```

to

```
map.get(true).stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("abc")))
```

---

Another solution you could do is:

```
Set<String> allIds = allPeople.stream().map(Person::id).collect(toSet());
List<String> orderedIds = Stream.concat(allIds.stream()
                        .filter(s -> "abc".equals(s) || "bob".equals(s))
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("abc"))),
                allIds.stream().filter(s -> !"abc".equals(s) && !"bob".equals(s)))
                .collect(toList());
```

which is pretty much doing the same thing as the above `partitioningBy` but just in a different approach.

---

Finaly, you might be surprised but your approach actually seems good, so you may want to complete it with:

```
Set<String> allIds = allPeople.stream().map(Person::id).collect(toSet());

List<String> orderedIds = new ArrayList<>();

if(allIds.contains("abc")) 
    orderedIds.add("abc");

if(allIds.contains("bob")) 
    orderedIds.add("bob");

orderedIds.addAll(allIds.stream().filter(s -> !"abc".equals(s) && ! "bob".equals(s)).collect(toList()));
```

Comment: Sweet. That's pretty interesting.  what is the guarantee that abc will be before Bob ?

Comment: @user1692342 if you're going with the first approach and use the provided comparator then "abc" will always be before "bob" and the second approach will accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Stuart Marks there is an even simpler solution:

```
List<String> allIds = allPeople.stream()
      .map(Person::getId)
      .distinct()
      .sorted(comparing(x -> !"abc".equals(x)).thenComparing(x -> !"bob".equals(x)))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```